# In code its shows no match bracket found but script gets executed in php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

```
  <?php
 include_once 'dbconnect.php';

   if(isset($_POST['page']))
   {
$page = $_POST['page'];
//@$author=$_REQUEST['author'];
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;
$per_page=10;

$previous_btn = true;
$next_btn = true;
$first_btn = true;
$last_btn = true;
$start = $page * $per_page;

if(!empty($_POST['run']))
{
 $value1=$_POST['run'];
 $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE a.run like '%$value1%' ";
    }
    else if(!empty($_POST['project']))
    {
     $value1=$_POST['project'];
     $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE a.project like '%$value1%'"; 
    }
    else if(!empty($_POST['sample']))
    {
     $value1=$_POST['sample'];
     $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE a.sample_id like '%$value1%'"; 
    }
    else if(!empty($_POST['bases']))
   {
     $values=$_POST['select1'];
     if($values=='greaterthan')
      {
       $value1=$_POST['bases'];
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) > '$value1' ORDER by (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) asc";
      } 
      else if($values=='greaterthanorequal')
      {
       $value1=$_POST['bases'];
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) >= '$value1' ORDER by (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) asc "; 
      } 
      else if($values=='lessthan')
      {
      $value1=$_POST['bases'];
      $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) < '$value1' ORDER by (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) desc "; 
      }
      else if($values=='lessthanorequal')
      {
       $value1=$_POST['bases'];
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) <= '$value1' ORDER by (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) desc ";
      }
      else if($values=='equal')
      {
       $value1=$_POST['bases'];
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) = '$value1' ";
      }
    }

    else if(!empty($_POST['reads']))
    {
     $values2=$_POST['select2'];
     if($values2=='greaterthan')
      {
       $value5=$_POST['reads'];
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) > '$value5' ORDER by (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) asc";
      }
      else if($values2=='greaterthanorequal')
      {
       $value5=$_POST['reads'];
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) >= '$value5' ORDER by (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) asc";
      }
      else if($values2=='lessthan')
      {
       $value5=$_POST['reads'];
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) < '$value5' ORDER by (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) desc";
      }
      else if($values2=='lessthanorequal')
      {
       $value5=$_POST['reads'];
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) <= '$value5' ORDER by (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) desc";
      }
      else if($values2=='equal')
      {
       $value5=$_POST['reads'];
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_reads + IFNULL(c.raw_reads2,0)) = '$value5' ";
      }
    } 
   if((!empty($_POST['run'])) && (!empty($_POST['project'])))
    {
 $valueR=$_POST['run'];
     $valueP=$_POST['project'];
     $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE a.run like '%$valueR%' AND a.project like '%$valueP%'"; 
    }  
    else if((!empty($_POST['project'])) && (!empty($_POST['sample'])))
     {
  $valueP=$_POST['project'];
      $valueS=$_POST['sample'];
      $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE a.project like '%$valueP%' AND a.sample_id like '%$valueS%'"; 
     } 
     else if((!empty($_POST['sample'])) && (!empty($_POST['run'])))
     {
  $valueS=$_POST['sample'];
      $valueR=$_POST['run'];
      $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE a.sample_id like '%$valueS%' AND a.run like '%$valueR%'"; 
     } 
     else if((!empty($_POST['run'])) && (!empty($_POST['bases'])))
     {
  $valueR=$_POST['run'];
      $values3=$_POST['select1'];
        if($values3=='greaterthan')
        {
       $value123=$_POST['bases'];
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) > '$value123' AND a.run LIKE '%$valueR%' ORDER by (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) ASC ";
        } 
        else if($values3=='lessthan')
        {
       $value123=$_POST['bases'];
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) < '$value123' AND a.run LIKE '%$valueR%' ORDER by (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) DESC ";
        } 
       else if($values3=='greaterthanorequal')
        {
       $value123=$_POST['bases'];
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) >= '$value123' AND a.run LIKE '%$valueR%' ORDER by (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) ASC ";
        }
       else if($values3=='lessthanorequal')
        {
       $value123=$_POST['bases'];
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) <= '$value123' AND a.run LIKE '%$valueR%' ORDER by (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) DESC ";
        } 
       else if($values3=='equal')
        {
       $value123=$_POST['bases'];
       $sql="SELECT a.run, a.lane, a.project, a.sample_id,a.end_type,b.raw_bases, b.raw_reads, c.raw_bases2, c.raw_reads2 FROM cp_sampleSheet a left JOIN cp_samp_R1 b ON a.sample_id = b.sample_id left JOIN cp_samp_R2 c ON a.sample_id =c.sample_id WHERE (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) = '$value123' AND a.run LIKE '%$valueR%' ORDER by (b.raw_bases + IFNULL(c.raw_bases2,0)) ";
        }
       }
}
  if( @$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql." LIMIT $start, $per_page " ) )    {
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
     ?>
   <table width="85%" border="1" align="center" id='t01' >
     <tr>
      <th>Sno </th>
      <th>Run</th>
      <th>Lane</th>
     <th>Sample Name</th>
     <th>End Type</th>
    <th>Project Name</th>
     <th>Total Raw Bases</th>
     <th>Bases(In Gbp)</th>
    <th>Total Raw Reads</th>
    <th>Reads(In Mbp)</th>
  </tr>
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    ?>
           <tr>
           <td align="center"><?php echo ++$counter;?> </td>        
           <td align="center"><?php echo $row['run'] ;?> </td>
           <td align="center"><?php echo $row['lane'] ;?> </td>
           <td align="center"><?php echo $row['sample_id']; ?></td>   

            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['end_type'] ;?> </td>
           <td align="center"><?php echo $row['project'] ;?> </td>

            <td align="center"><?php  $a=(($row['raw_bases'])+($row['raw_bases2'])); echo $a;?> </td>
             <td align="center"><?php  $a=(($row['raw_bases'])+($row['raw_bases2']))/1000000000; $var = floor($a*100)/100; echo $var;?> </td>
              <td align="center"><?php  $b=(($row['raw_reads'])+($row['raw_reads2'])); echo $b;?> </td>
               <td align="center"><?php  $b=(($row['raw_reads'])+($row['raw_reads2']))/1000000; $var = floor($b*100)/100; echo $var;?>    </td>


  </tr>
   <?php
    }

    // Close result set
   // mysqli_free_result($result);
  } 
 else{
     echo  " No records matching your query were found.";
  }
   ?>
    </table>
```

I have a problem with braces in my script. When I close the braces before `if( @$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql." LIMIT $start, $per_page " ) )` it shows that bracket match out of range but code is working fine. Also, can I use `else if` at `if((!empty($_POST['run'])) && (!empty($_POST['project'])))`? I used `else if` but code does not work. Can anybody tell me what the problem is?

Comment: You've got more opening brackets (29) than closing (28) ... now have fun finding out where the mismatch is.

Comment: there is no extra braces once see closing before f( @$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql." LIMIT $start, $per_page " ) )

Comment: Open it in something like Notepad++ do Ctrl + F for `{` and count - then count the number of `}` - there's one more `{` than `}`

Comment: Hi CD001, can i have ur email id plz